# Is it possible to lock a kiosk mode application from another app?

Tags: android, kiosk-mode

I have an application in kiosk mode. I enable kiosk mode with the method below and am able to enter kiosk mode by calling startLockTask().

Here is the method that allows kiosk mode:

```
private void enableKioskMode() {
    Log.i(TAG, "enableKioskMode");

    ComponentName deviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);
    DevicePolicyManager mDpm  = (DevicePolicyManager)
            getSystemService    (Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

    // First of all, to access anything this app must be the device owner.
    if (mDpm.isDeviceOwnerApp   (getPackageName())) {

        // It also needs to be device admin. If it's not, ask to become one.
        if (!mDpm.isAdminActive (deviceAdmin) &&
                mDpm.isDeviceOwnerApp(getPackageName())) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Not device admin. Asking device owner to become one.");

            Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, deviceAdmin);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                    "You need to be a device admin to enable kiosk mode.");

            startActivity(intent);
        }

        // This app is device owner and admin :now  set the apps that can use kiosk mode.
        else {
            mDpm.setLockTaskPackages(deviceAdmin, new String[] {
                    getPackageName(), "com.application.test1",
                    "com.aplication.test2"
            });
        }
    }

    // This app is not device owner - It can't access anything.
    else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Not device owner.");
        Toast.makeText(this, "This application is not the device owner.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I can switch from this application to com.application.test1 by calling stopLockTask() in this app, switching to com.application.test1, and calling startLockTask() from that app.

My question is, is it possible to lock another app dynamically from the original app? Ie, instead of switching to com.application.test1, I want to switch to com.application.test2 and have it stay in kiosk mode without having to call startLockTask() again from com.application.test2. Can I maybe initiate the startLockTask() from the original application?